# Avoid curl to check for malformed URLs

Tags: curl

I have observed a change of behaviour in curl between versions:

With curl 7.74.0

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/v2/entities?q=a==12;    '
# My server at 9999 responses with a proper 400 Bad Request to the malformed URL

$ curl --version
curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-12-09
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

With curl 7.88.1

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/v2/entities?q=a==12;    '
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

$ curl --version
curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.88.1 OpenSSL/3.0.9 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.4 libidn2/2.3.3 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.52.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2023-02-20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

It seems curl has changed behavior from version 7.74 to 7.88 and URLs that were processed before are now detected as "malformed URLs". (In particular, the URL in the example above is malformed due to the trailing whitespace at the end).

Although I understand this can be seen as an improvement, I'm using curl to test how my server processes malformed requests. If curl reuses to use such malformed URLs, I cannot see how my server reacts to it.

I have two particular questions, please:

- In which version (between 7.74 and 7.88) did this behavior change?
- Is there some way to tell curl 7.88 to behave as before (some "avoid URL checking" CLI switch or similar)? In negative case, is there another alternative tool to do the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: In addition, only one question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: @Evert thanks for your valuable feedback. I'd have a look to changelog and try to self-answer my first question

Comment: @Rob thanks for your feedback. With regards your first comment, in [What topics can I ask about here? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) one of the topics is "software tools commonly used by programmers". Under my understanding, `curl` is a software tool widely used among the community of network application programmers, so the post makes sense here. With regards your second comment, I think they are related sub-questions, so it makes sense to keep them together in the same post. The alternative (duplicate almost the same post in a separate one) it worse, IMHO.

Comment: Note also `curl` label (for the tool), which is different from the `libcurl` label (for the library). If curl (tool) is out of the scope here, why to keep both labels? In my opinion the existence of both labels supports the point that questions about curl (as "software tools commonly used by programmers") make sense in SO.

Comment: curl is a utility program and has nothing to do with programming itself. No different than asking a question about any other OS utility. Asking more than one question, however related, detracts from the main thread. SO is one question, one answer.

Comment: @Evert what do you think about splitting the post into two ones? All the text up to "I have two particular questions, please:" will be the same in each post...

Comment: I think people are way to aggressive telling people they're asking questions wrong, and should spend more of that time helping people ;). That said, it is probably a real rule on stack overflow.

Comment: But anyway, _standard HTTP clients_ tend to not be good at testing violations of the HTTP spec, unless it's a specific goal of those clients to support that. If you're just testing a HTTP/1.1 endpoint without TLS, it's probably just the easiest to open a socket and send bad data manually.